# Eigenvectors don't seem to align with eigenvalues in np.linalg.eig

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't quite see it.  I'm doing some sanity checks on `np.linalg.eig`, and can't verify that the eigenvectors and eigenvalues are being returned in the correct order.

Here's a quick example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np

boston = load_boston()

X     = boston['data']
left  = X @ X.T

uvals, U = np.linalg.eig(left)
uvals, U = uvals.real, U.real
```

Now, just as a quick sanity check, I check the following values

```
U[:, 0] * uvals[0]
left @ U[:, 0]
```

These two lines return an identical value, as I would expect.

However, if I use eigenvectors / values at different indices I don't get equal results from these operations.

For example the following two lines return different values:

```
U[:, 18] * uvals[18]
left @ U[:, 18]
```

If I sum the values returned by each line they are also different, so it's not that the numbers are appearing in different orders.  I assume there is something I'm missing, but I'd appreciate clarification on how exactly this method returns its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.  I assumed they would correspond to each other at their indices, but according to this example they don't.

Comment: I think the problem might be numerical, if you check multiple lines in plot, the error in line 18 is order 1e-10, but in the row 0 the magnitude is near 1e7 (i think this amplitude between values is the problem)

Comment: You say *"For example the following two lines return different values:"*; show the actual values.  Normal floating point imprecision can result in small differences in computations that are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: At least when I print them, these are all numbers smaller in magnitude 1e-10. You can't really hope for much at that magnitude (`np.isclose` uses an absolute tolerance of 1e-9). For more precise results, you'll need something like `decimal` to help.